# Hiding Tab headers in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I have tried several ways but I could not manage to do it. How can I hide the tab headers in tabcontrols in ***Silverlight***. I have searched on the Internet but mostly the solutions are for WPF.

I have buttons to navigate between tabs but I do not want user to see the headers.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you can style them away, try something with the TabHeaderStyle / ItemTemplate (TabControl derives from ItemsControl) before you resort to overwriting the control template for the TabControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin suggested, i used microsoft templates to fix the problem.

Firstly there are good default templates for TabItem and TabControl on this [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035(VS.95).aspx). I used them.

This code is for silverlight 5, and for silvelight 3 or 4, you need to change "sdk". You need to use like the one in the site that I give.

I just took the related part of the template, I am not sure to take all the template and update only this related part. However when use like the code below, i.e, only related part of the template, it works fine.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column="1" >
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="sdk:TabControl" x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:TabControl">
                    <!--here comes the template-->  
                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateTop" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <controlsPrimitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelTop" Margin="2,2,2,-1" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border MinHeight="10" MinWidth="10" Grid.Row="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentTop" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualTop" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Background="#8CFFFFFF" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3"/>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>

<sdk:TabControl Style="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
    <sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <!--your tabes comes here-->  
</sdk:TabControl></StackPanel>
```

I think you can directly use the part between

```
<StackPanel.Resources>...</StackPanel.Resources>
```

I hope it helps the people who have the same problem.

There is also a similar problem and answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/6395a40f-f5dc-4ba9-b848-2d844b72059c/how-to-hide-tabitem-headers?forum=silverlightcontrols).